# how to combine both orientations (vertical and horizontal) displaying bucket list in shiny from package sortable?

Tags: r, shiny, sortablejs

I want to display bucket list from sortable package in specific way and combine horizontal and vertical orientations in one object. Unfortunately, it is possible to set argument orientation using only one of them. Is there any method to get below layout of bucket list ?

I aim to get bucket list with 3 rank lists inside - on the left side I want to display Part1 list and on the right side - Part2 and Part3 (one above the other)

[image: the schame what I want to get finally]

My current code below - so far I am able to display either horizontal or vertical orientation (I need combine both of them)

```
ui <- fluidPage(

bucket_list(
     header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
     group_name = "bucket_list_group",
     orientation = "horizontal",

add_rank_list(text = "Part1",
              labels = list(
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"),
              input_id = "part1"),

add_rank_list(text = "Part2",
              labels = list(
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"),
              input_id = "part2"),

add_rank_list(text = "Part3",
              labels = list(
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"),
              input_id = "part3")
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("bucket_list")
 )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$bucket_list <- renderPrint(input$bucket_list_group)

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any hint or advise is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution as you can have to `bucket_list` with same `group_name` separately and organize them into one row with two columns.

There is a minor downside is you need to reference to each `part` specifically instead of using `group_name`

#### UI side

Using `fluidRow` & `column`

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           bucket_list(
             header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
             group_name = "bucket_list_group",
             orientation = "horizontal",
             
             add_rank_list(text = "Part1",
                           labels = list(
                             "one",
                             "two",
                             "three"),
                           input_id = "part1"),
           ),
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           bucket_list(
             header = " ",
             group_name = "bucket_list_group",
             orientation = "vertical",
             add_rank_list(text = "Part2",
                           labels = list(
                             "1",
                             "2",
                             "3"),
                           input_id = "part2"),
             
             add_rank_list(text = "Part3",
                           labels = list(
                             "A",
                             "B",
                             "C"),
                           input_id = "part3")
           )
    )
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("bucket_list")
)
```

#### Server side

Need to use `input$part1, input$part2, input$part3` instead - The `input$bucket_list_group` is not contains all three parts anymore.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$bucket_list <- renderPrint(list(input$part1, input$part2, input$part3))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]